# invalid date symfony when submitting form

Tags: symfony, datepicker

I created a date field type date which show the month's name in text format (12-January-2016) on my FormType. so I

```
$builder->add('debut_contrat', DateType::class,  array(
    'format' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
    'widget'=>'single_text',
    'attr' => array_merge($isDisabled, array(
         'placeholder' => 'Debut contrat'
    ))
));
```

when I submit the form, it return invalid date.
I don't know where's the bug.
Hopping your help, thank you

Comment: In the `'fomat' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'`

Comment: What are you putting in the form for the date? "12-January-2016"? If you are using a datepicker make sure the value that is being sent to the server is in the right format

Comment: all right, the value was sent but the validation is failed, I thint its cause is the type of generated field is text not date where as it expecting a date object, so what I did is to convert the value to object date. My question is, why doesn't symfony convert the text field